# How can I use an IF or Case function to summarize a GROUP_CONCAT column? AND then apply it to the original data table?

Tags: mysql, case, mysql-workbench, group-concat

I am quite the novice at MYSQL and would appreciate any pointers - the goal here would be to automate a categorical field using GROUP_CONCAT in a certain way, and then summarize certain patterns in the GROUP_CONCAT field in a new_column. Furthermore, is it possible to add the new_column to the original table in one query? Below is what I've tried and errors to an unknown column "Codes" if this assists:

```
SELECT 
    `ID`,
    `Code`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `Code` ORDER BY `Code` ASC SEPARATOR ", ") AS `Codes`,
    IF(`Codes` LIKE '123%', 'Description1',
        IF(`Codes` = '123, R321', 'Description2', 
            "Logic Needed"))
FROM Table1
GROUP BY `ID`
```

Instead of nested if statements, I would like to have a CASE statement as a substitute. Reason being is that I already have around 1000 lines of logical already written as "If [column] = "?" Then "?" else if" etc. I feel like using CASE would be an easier transition with the logic. Maybe something like:

```
SELECT 
    `ID`,
    `Code`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `Code` ORDER BY `Code` ASC SEPARATOR ", ") AS `Codes`,
    CASE
        WHEN `Codes` LIKE '123%' THEN 'Description1'
        WHEN `Codes` = '123, R321' THEN 'Description2'
        ELSE "Logic Needed"
    END
FROM Table1
GROUP BY `ID`
```

Table Example:

```
ID,Code
1,R321
1,123
2,1234
3,1231
4,123
4,R321
```

Completed Table:

```
ID,Codes,New_Column
1,"123, R321",Description2
2,1234,Description1
3,1231,Description1
4,"123, R321",Description2
```

How then can I add back the summarized data to the original table?

Final Table:

```
ID,Code,New_Column
1,R321,Description2
1,123,Description2
2,1234,Description1
3,1231,Description1
4,123,Description2
4,R321,Description2
```

Thanks.

Comment: You use incorrect conditions order. When `Codes = '123, R321'` then it matches `Codes LIKE '123%'` too - hence 2nd option will be selected never. Swap them (always put detailed pattern before common one).

Comment: Good catch, this is technically a posting error on my part. Will be sure to take into consideration on my project. Thanks, Akina.

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to a column alias in the same query. You need to do the `GROUP_CONCAT()` in a subquery, then the main query can refer to `Codes` to summarize it.

It also doesn't make sense to select `Code`, since there isn't a single `Code` value in the group.

```
SELECT ID, Codes, 
    CASE
        WHEN `Codes` = '123, R321' THEN 'Description2'
        WHEN `Codes` LIKE '123%' THEN 'Description1'
        ELSE "Logic Needed"
    END AS New_Column
FROM (
    SELECT 
        `ID`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `Code` ORDER BY `Code` ASC SEPARATOR ", ") AS `Codes`
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY ID
) AS x
```

As mentioned in a comment, the `WHEN` clauses are tested in order, so you need to put the more specific cases first. You might want to use `FIND_IN_SET()` rather than `LIKE`, since `123%` will match `1234`, not just `123, something`

Comment: Fantastic, Barmar. I will test things soon and let you know. Also, for the ordering of the CASE statement - I completely understand; I rewrote my example to make sense with ASC and did not reorder the WHEN statements. Thank you kindly for your time and assistance.